# Date Functions in SQL

Tags: sql, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to check when a persons certification is due within the next 3 months.  I want this to be able to execute correctly no matter when it is executed.  A person has to renew their certification every 6 months.

Here is my code so far:

```
 SELECT CERT_DATE "Date Of Last Cert Test",
  add_months(CERT_DATE, 6)"Date Due"
 FROM TESTING.CERTS
 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CERT_DATE "Date Of Last Cert Test",
       ADD_MONTHS(CERT_DATE, 6) "Date Due"
FROM TESTING.CERTS
WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(CURRENT_DATE, CERT_DATE) <= 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CERT_DATE [DateOfLastCertTest], 
DATEADD(MONTH, 6, CERT_DATE) [DateDue]
FROM TESTING.CERTS
```

Comment: [,] are invalid in SQL identifiers

Comment: I guess it depends on which version of SQL you're running.  I can't use the double-quotes in SQL 2012, and had to use the square brackets.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, its not vaild in Oracle SQL Developer.  I should of stated that before.